# Nextjs Image as Layout background

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, next.js

I have this main page.js code that displays an image as the background using Next Image component, but I actually want this background throughout my whole app. So I guess I should create a layout and add it there but should I do it in my RootLayout because I want it to be global to all my pages.

so my question really is how can I add a background next image that is common to all pages?

thank you.

```
import UserFields from "@/components/UserFields";
import Image from "next/image";
import background from "../public/benagil.jpg"

export default function Home() {

  return (
    <div className=" relative z-10">
      <div className=" relative h-full w-full flex flex-col items-center justify-center text-center z-10">
        <Intro />
        <UserFields />
        <Image className="z-0 opacity-50"
          src={background}
          alt={"background"}
          quality={100}
          fill={true}
          sizes="100vw"
          objectFit="cover"
          placeholder="blur"
        />
        </div>
    </div>

  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add background image throughout your whole app, you have to put the Next Image component in `RootLayout`. And add a position property on body like `fixed`

```js
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="ko-KR">
      <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" sizes="any" />
      <body>
        {children}
        <Image className="z-0 opacity-50"
          src={background}
          alt={"background"}
          quality={100}
          fill={true}
          sizes="100vw"
          objectFit="cover"
          placeholder="blur"
        />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

or add a background-image property(css) on body tag.
And I don't recommend setting the quality to 100, default is 75 (as you probably know)

Comment: Since the image will be Largest Contentful Paint (LCP) you should also add `priority` to preload the Image.